# Flask - Deserialize JSON and load to Postgres DB

Tags: python, json, reactjs, postgresql, flask

I have a front-end React app with backend Flask.
When a form is submitted from React, I want to send the data to the backend flask application, then add it to the Postgres DB.

React - handleSubmit

```
  handleSubmit(event){

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/results', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            return response.json();
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

When the submitted form creates the object below, how could I add deserialize the json data, and add a row in postgres?

```
{
name: Bob,
location: New York, NY,
days: {Mon: true, Tue: false, Wed: true, Thu: false, Fri: true}
}
```

This is what I have so far in python - I have the api_post function that posts the data from react, and then I have the sqlalchemy schema of how I want the data to look like in the table. How do I integrate the marshmallow library or pickling in this case to save each json data as its own separate column?

```
#api.py

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from config import DATABASE_URI

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DATABASE_URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#getting the data from React
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def api_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        shift = request.json
        db.session.add(jsonify(shift))
        db.session.commit()

#database schema


class Shifts(db.Model):

     __table__ = 'shifts'

     emp_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
     name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
     location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
     mon = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
     tue = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
     wed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
     thu = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
     fri = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
     
     def __init__(self, name, location, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri):
          self.name = name
          self.location = location
          self.mon = mon
          self.tue = tue
          self.wed = wed
          self.thu = thu
          self.fri = fri

db.create_all()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'flask.wrappers.Response' is not mapped. But that

Answer (score 1):

Typicly you would want to validate the user input before saving it to the database but for the sake of simplicity I will ignore this part.

The error you are getting is because flask's `jsonify` returns a Response object with headers set to application/json for you.  `request.json` should already have your json parsed into a dictionary (we shall ignore the fact that the property is called json when it is in fact a dictionary and not json).

Now that we have the user input as a dictionary we can use it to create a Shifts object that we can then add to the database.  Here is an example of just the route, the rest of your code would stay the same:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def api_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        try:
            shift = Shifts(
              name=data["name"],
              location=data["location"],
              mon=data["mon"],
              tue=data["tue"],
              wed=data["wed"],
              thu=data["thu"],
              fri=data["fri"],
            )
        except KeyError:
            return "missing required value", 400

        db.session.add(shift)
        db.session.commit()

        return "", 201
```